# Call function in class in php through ajax in core

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

I have class named as example and class consist of functions like login, logout, send mail etc., how can i call the functions in php class through ajax or though form action.
For example we are calling function in framework like yii as like this `'<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/action')'`, Here here controller is class. I know to use in framework. My question is how to use class functions through ajax in core

Example

Class.php

```
Class example
{
 function login()
  {
   echo "hi";
  }
 function logout
  {
   echo "logout";
  }
function sendmail()
 {
  echo "example";
 }
}
```

Ajax is following

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'classname/functionname or create object to call function',
     type: 'POST',
     success : function(data){
                             alert(data);
                             }
      });
```

if i want to login then URL will be like example/login

Comment: which version of Yii your are using?

Comment: I am using yii 1.1 . I know to use in framework but no in directly

Comment: what do you  mean call them directly from ajax?

Answer (score 0):

In Yii, all URLs are processed through a [Controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController) action. A Controller action is any method of the controller with a method name preceded by the word "action" e.g. `actionLogin()`.

Ajax makes a call from the client side to a URL(from the browser). Your 'example' class is not a Controller (doesn't extend Yii Controller class). So your class cannot process the request. You need to call a controller through the URL and the controller's action method (e.g. actionLogin()) will handle the request and can call your specific proprietary class internally.

**Example**

Client code (javascript/jquery):

```
$.ajax({
     url: '<?=Yii::app()->createUrl("site/login")?>', // actionLogin() of SiteController
     type: 'POST',
     success : function(data){
         alert(data);
     }
});
```

Server code (php/Yii):

```
Class SiteController extends CController() {

    public function actionLogin() {
        // Your example class. Use require or Yii::import() somewhere to load your class
        $eg = new Example();
        $eg->login();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to do it in framework...can you please tell me how to do it in the directly without framework

Comment: If you are using Yii you have to follow as I explained above. If you don't want to use Yii to handle the URL, then you have to check the webserver (nginx / apache / etc) on how default URL handling is done and work from there.